# Electrical installation diversification

Tags: design, home-installation

I have an exam in three hours and there seems to be a recurring question in all previous years questions:

Why are cooker units diversified while air conditioners are not?

I've searched a lot but have not found a satisfying answer, please explain it as simply as humanly possible.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that terminology may be a local one but you have no location in your user profile.

To me the most likely reason is for calculating total load on a system such as a transformer feeding a group of houses.

- Cookers will be used at somewhat diverse<sup>1</sup> times and for diverse durations by each household so the expected average and peak load will be a significant factor less than the sum of all the cookers.
- Air conditioning is very likely to be non-diverse as each home will experience the same heat input on a warm day and all AC units will turn on around the same time and for many hours at a time. The peak load will be the sum of all the AC units.

---

<sup>1</sup> (/dʌɪˈvəːs,ˈdʌɪvəːs/
*adjective*
showing a great deal of variety; very different.
Synonyms:   various, many and various, sundry, manifold, multiple)

Comment: Thank you, that helps.

Comment: Actually, people DO tend to all cook at around the same times of the day. But they rarely use the full capacity of the cooker all at once.